# Why does sox corrupt my wav file when I try and change the sample rate?

Tags: audio, sox

When I try to use sox to change the sample rate of a wav file I get a file of noise and garbage and the 2 following errors:

```
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 579 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 518 samples; decrease volume?
```

Although there are question marks there, I never get to answer them.  They come up more as a status.

What I am starting with is a PCM file of my own making.  The specs are:

```
16 bit signed
big endian
1 channel 
44100 sample rate
```

I can import the file (0.wav) into Audacity and it's fine.

Then I convert the file into a wav file with the following line:

```
sox -r 44100 -e signed-integer  -b 16 -c 1 0.raw 1.wav
```

I can import that file into Audacity and it also is fine.

But then when I try to change the sampling rate with:

```
sox 1.wav -r 16000 2.wav
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, or missing, I would appreciate it.  Also I put up the original raw here:  http://warptv.com/raw.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem of endian-ness. Your raw file is stored in big endian byte order, while WAV is, [at least most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111539/is-the-endianness-of-format-params-guaranteed-in-riff-wav-files), [little-endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692465/why-are-an-integers-bytes-stored-backwards-does-this-apply-to-headers-only).

This being the case you have to explicitly inform SoX about the endian-ness of your raw file, so this can be taken into account when converting. The appropriate switch for this is `-B`, changing your command into something like:

```
sox -r 44100 -e signed-integer -B -b 16 -c 1 0.raw 1.wav
```

With the raw file properly converted into a wav file the subsequent rate conversion as you attempted it should work as expected. At least it did for me.

Playing around a bit with Audacity it appears that it has some method of detecting (or guessing) the endian-ness of raw files that SoX lacks, and that this is the source of the discrepancy you found.

Comment: That was it, bingo.  Thanks